# Query Builder filter for multi level deep relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-query-builder

I have a selection of plots which each belong to a development by a hasManyThrough relationship through housetypes. I want to filter these by development on their overview page. Plots has a housetype_id column and housetypes has a development_id column.

```
public function plots()
  {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Plot::class, Housetype::class);
  }
```

When I use my filter it returns the developments ID number as $development, I then need this to only show plots which are linked to that development.

I have looked into using whereHas or Join methods but have been unable to figure this out. Current filter scope is below. Thanks

```
public function scopeFilterDevelopment($query)
    {
      $development = request()->input('filter_development');

      if ($development == "") {
        return;
      }

      if(!empty($development)){
        $query->where('development_id', $development);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a whereHas that solved this in the end! (another developer at work walked me through this)

Relationship -

```
public function housetype()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Housetype::class);
    }
```

Function -

```
public function scopeFilterDevelopment($query)
    {
      if (request()->input('filter_development') == "") {
        return;
      }else{
        $query->whereHas('housetype', function($housetype){
          $housetype->where('development_id', request()->input('filter_development'));
        });
      }
    }
```

This then returns any plot where its housetype has a matching development_id for the filter_development from the request.

Thanks for everyone's input

Answer (score 0):

If I can understand it right you wish to assert a condition on other Model, `HasMany` will load all the objects to the related model once the query is completed. Eloquent then binds the related model objects to each.

Try `joins` from Laravel instead. I feel this is what you exactly want: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

Answer (score 0):

I would use whereHas to filter the relationship:

```php
YourModel::whereHas('plots', function($query) {
    $query->filterDevelopment();
})->get();
```

I would also edit the query scope not to rely on the request global function, but instead pass the development of value as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you have make a leftjon and then use when, you dont have to use

```
if(!empty($development)){
    $query->where('development_id', $development);
  }
```

this any more,  you can use

```
->when($development=="" ? false : true, function($query) use ($development){
return $query->where('development_id', $development);
})
```

this is a full example

```
$queryBuilder =  DB::table('facturas')->
leftJoin('clientes','clientes.id','=','facturas.clientes_id')->
select('facturas.estados_id as estado','facturas.numero as 
numero',DB::raw('concat(clientes.nombre," ",clientes.apellido) as cliente'))->
when($estados===null ? false: true,function($query) use ($estados){
    return $query->whereIn('facturas.estados_id', $estados);
                        })
```